# Insert an element in a specified position in a given array

Tags: c

How can I insert a value in specific position in C?

For example:

```
const char filenameC[] ="AndModel.c"; 
FILE * fileC=fopen(filenameC,"r"); 

int LineNumber=1; 
char line[200],search_string[]="similar";
if( fileC)
{

while ( fgets ( line, 200, fileC ) != NULL ) 
   {
        if(strstr(line,search_string))
        {
            fputs ( line, stdout );
            printf("%d", LineNumber);  
        }   
    LineNumber++; 
    }
}

FILE * fileW=fopen(filenameC,"w"); 
fseek(fileW, LineNumber,SEEK_SET); 
fputs("hello",fileW); 

printf("\n"); 

return 0;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert element into array C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44378012/insert-element-into-array-c)

Answer (score 0):

Alright here's your solution:

```
        for (int i = number_of_elements -1; i >= desired_position; i--)
        {
            line[i + 1] = line[i];
        }

        line[desired_position] = value;
```

So in the case of your code, if I wanted to insert an element of the array to position 3, and set that value to 'd', then I would just do it like this:

```
if (fileC)
{
  while (fgets (line, 200, fileC) != NULL)
  {
    if (strstr (line, search_string))
      {
         for (int i = 200 - 1; i >= 3; i--)
         {
            line[i+1] = line[i];
         } 

         line[3] = 'd';

        printf ("%s", line);
        fputs (line, stdout);
        printf ("%d", LineNumber);
      }
      LineNumber++;
    }
}
```