# Error: assignment to expression with array type, when assigning values to an array

Tags: arrays, c, assign

I would like to insert value into the array's last position. So, I created the function insert. This function returns the new array.

In this code, I would like to insert `value=0` into `array={1}`'s last position and assign the new array to an array I declare at the beginning of the main.

So I wrote:

```
array = insert(&array[0], value, NUM(array), NUM(array)+1)
```

However, I received the error:

```
ERROR:  assignment to expression with array type` in the line:  
`array = insert(&array[0], value, NUM(array), NUM(array)+1);
```

but if I declare a `new_array` this error does not occur.

I would like to know why this occurs and how to solve it.

Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define NUM(a) (sizeof(a) / sizeof(*a))

int * insert(int *, int, int, int);

void main(){
    int array[] = {1};
//  int *new_array;
    int value = 0;
    int num = 3;
    int pos = 2;
    array = insert(&array[0], value, NUM(array), NUM(array)+1);
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < NUM(array); i++) {
      printf("array[%d] = %d\n", i, array[i]);
   }
}



int * insert(int *p, int a, int N, int pos){
    int i;
//   // now shift rest of the elements downwards    
//  for(i = N; i >= 0; i--) {
//      p[i+1] = p[i];
//  }
    
    // increase the size by 1
    N++;
    
    // shift elements forward
    for (i = N-1; i >= pos; i--)
        p[i] = p[i - 1];
 
    // insert x at pos
    p[pos - 1] = a;
    
    return p;
    
}
```

Comment: You need to assign to an *element* of the array.  You can't assign to the array itself.  The error message essentially said just that.  So if `a` is an array, you cannot do `a = ...`.  You need to do `a[i] = ...`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insert element into array C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44378012/insert-element-into-array-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C, array names are **non modifiable** lvalues. You cannot assign anything to an array variable. Hence, you are getting error on this statement:

```
array = insert(&array[0], value, NUM(array), NUM(array)+1);
```

`new_array` is a pointer and remember arrays and pointers are different. When you access an array, it is converted to a pointer to first element (there are few exceptions to this rule)<sup>1)</sup>.

Also note that

```
int array[] = {1};
```

the size of array `array` is `1`. When you omit the dimension of an array, compiler deduce it based on the size of initialiser and you are initialising `array` with only one element. So, the array `array` is an array of *one* `int` type element.

That means, this

```
int array[] = {1};
```

is same as this

```
int array[1] = {1};
```

You are passing `NUM(array)+1` to `insert()` function and accessing `array` element at `pos` index, where `pos` value is `NUM(array)+1`, i.e. accessing array beyond its size, which is an [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Also, you should not use `void` as return type of `main()` function . As per C language standards, the return type of `main()` function should be `int`.

---

1. From C11 Standards#6.3.2.1p3 *[emphasis added]*

> 3 Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator, the _Alignof operator, or the unary & operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has type ''array of type'' is converted to an expression with type ''pointer to type'' that points to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue. ....